# Prophet_Plot_Components Output

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the package prophet in R. I was able to create a plot showing the seasonality of my dataset by I do not know how to get the raw outputs. I do not want to eyeball my solution. Is there a way to do this in this package?

```
library(prophet)
m<-prophet(df, yearly.seasonality = TRUE)
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)
```

Output:

[image]

How do I get the actual numeric values from this graph, especially the bottom one showing the yearly seasonality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy actually.

Just write:

```
forecast
```

And it will give you all the trends for each chart